# Mac Window Won't Let Me Resize to Smaller, possibly constraints?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nslayoutconstraint

I'm not positive about what is going wrong, but my guess is that it is constraints related.

When I try to resize my NSWindow, I'm able to make it larger without a problem. However, when I try to make it smaller, the window won't change size at all. Very few elements in the window have constraints with fixed sizes. The total fixed width is only about 120 and my window is about 700 wide, so I'm not running into a fixed width problem. In fact, if I drag the window to 800 wide, then it's min size becomes 800.

My guess is that once the views have increased in size they don't want to compress back down. But that's just a guess.

Any idea how to address this? Sorry that I can't provide any code, but I don't have any code involved. It's all just constraints in my xib.

EDIT:

I added an NSLog of `[self.window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]` to `- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification`. At first the window lets me resize it larger and smaller, and this is what the output looks like:

```
2015-03-20 17:41:40.097 10bii Financial Calculator[19780:561394] windowDidResize Constraints: (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000081d10 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x618000121400]   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100902d90'10bii Financial Calculator' )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000081d60 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSView:0x618000121400]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100902d90'10bii Financial Calculator' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000856e0 'NSWindow-current-width' H:[NSThemeFrame:0x100902d90'10bii Financial Calculator'(872@500)] priority:500>"
)
```

Then, after a few resizes, the window stops allowing me to make it smaller and this is the output of the constraints log:

```
2015-03-20 17:42:03.506 10bii Financial Calculator[19780:561394] windowDidResize Constraints: (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000081d10 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x618000121400]   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100902d90'10bii Financial Calculator' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008d570 H:|-(0)-[ViewWithBackground:0x608000142c00]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x618000121400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008d520 H:[ViewWithBackground:0x608000142c00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x618000121400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000829e0 H:[NSTextField:0x608000180dd0]-(20)-[NSTextField:0x608000180d00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082940 NSTextField:0x608000180dd0.width == 3*NSTextField:0x608000180d00.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082850 NSTextField:0x608000180dd0.width == 3*NSTextField:0x608000180c30.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082800 NSTextField:0x608000180dd0.width == 3*NSTextField:0x608000180b60.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000827b0 NSTextField:0x608000180dd0.width == 3*NSTextField:0x608000180a90.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082ad0 H:[NSTextField:0x608000180d00]-(20)-[NSTextField:0x608000180c30]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000828f0 NSTextField:0x608000180dd0.width == 3*NSTextField:0x6080001809c0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082b70 H:[NSTextField:0x608000180c30]-(20)-[NSTextField:0x608000180b60]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000828a0 NSTextField:0x608000180dd0.width == 2*NSTextField:0x6080001808f0.width
+ 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082c10 H:[NSTextField:0x608000180b60]-(20)-[NSTextField:0x608000180a90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082cb0 H:[NSTextField:0x608000180a90]-(20)-[NSTextField:0x6080001809c0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082d00 H:[NSTextField:0x6080001809c0]-(20)-[NSTextField:0x6080001808f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008d110 H:|-(20)-[NSTextField:0x608000180dd0]   (Names: '|':ViewWithBackground:0x608000142c00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008d340 H:[NSTextField:0x6080001808f0]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':ViewWithBackground:0x608000142c00 )>" )
```

Here is what the window looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably some of the views within your window have intrinsic content size and have compression resistance priority that's greater than or equal to 500 (`NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut`). Reduce the compression resistance priorities and that will allow the window to be made smaller.

If that's not clear enough, you're going to have to show what constraints there are within your window's view hierarchy.

Comment: I've sent every view in my xib to have a Content Compression Resistance Priority = 250, but the problem persists. How would you like me to show my constraints? The window has a lot of views in it. :/

Comment: You can expand the document outline in IB and post a screen shot of the constraints. Be sure to drag the split view divider wide enough to show the specifics. You could also try logging `[self.window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]` at some strategic point and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken Thomases' suggestion of logging ...

`[self.window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]`

was able to give me a clue as to which views were causing the problem. I had 7 text labels in a row across the window. Most of them were supposed to be Equal Width, but the one on each end was larger. The 1st is 3x the others and the last is 2x the others.

When I originally set up the constraints, I selected all of them and and applied the Equal Widths constraints, then I modified the multipliers. I noticed that the 3x label was the view that all of the others were EqualWidth'd to. I worried that ended up with an overly complicated arrangement. So I deleted those constraints, and reapplied them one at a time and made sure all of the same-sized labels were keyed to each other, then the 3x was keyed to one of the 1x labels.

Once I did that, the problem went away. Not exactly sure why, but perhaps this description will help someone else.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Yeah, I was focusing on those width constraints, too. In one case, instead of a 3x multiplier, there was a multiplier of 2 and a constant of 3 (i.e. 2x + 3), which may have caused the issue.

Comment: Gah... whatever change I made to those constraints are causing me more problems now. The animations in the rest of my views are chunky and I noticed those labels are twitching during the animation. I removed the constraints on those labels and my animations move smoothly. Blerg.